# Trying to run crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron, xubuntu

I'm trying to run a cron job with crontab -e.  I'm using a python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webbrowser
handle = webbrowser.get()
handle.open_new_tab('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4QGPWLY-EM')
```

running crontab -e i have:

```
* * * * * python /home/sean/imBlue.py >>/tmp/out.txt 2>&1
```

And i keep getting these error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sean/imBlue.py", line 3, in <module>
    handle = webbrowser.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 52, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

I'm not sure what I need to include or what I am doing wrong.  When I run the script in bash: python scriptName.py
I don't have any issues.  Also i have changed the settings of the file to chmod a+x.

Comment: Which browser do you use ?

Comment: I use firefox browser

Comment: `handle = webbrowser.get('firefox')`

Answer (score 2):

A `crontab` entry will run even if you are not logged, and does not keep the environment.

You need at least to set and export the `DISPLAY` variable in your crontab (assuming that indeed you are logged to an X11 session at time of crontab)

Perhaps changing the `crontab` entry to

```
  * * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 python /home/sean/imBlue.py >>/tmp/out.txt 2>&1
```

could help. Of course if you are not logged on at that time it won't work

<sup>My feeling is that your whole script is a huge mistake, or a bad trick: you don't want to play every minute a video of more than 5 minutes!</sup>

Comment: And how exactly would I do that